# Download of Lenovo IdeaPad S400 Win 8 recovery image

Tags: system-restore, lenovo-laptop

I bought an Lenovo IdeaPad S400 last week. To make a long story short (installed Windows 7), I now need to reinstall Windows 8, and the recovery partition on the hard disk no longer exists.

Normally I would order a recovery media from www.lenovorecovery.com, but the IdeaPad S400 does not figure on the site - it's not possible to order. I assume it might be something to do with, that the S400 doesn't have a DVD drive.

But what can I do then? Is there anywhere where I can download the image? I have a blank 16 GB usb stick to put it on and make bootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For products and countries that aren't covered by that web site (like the US and Canada), Lenovo instructs users to contact them to order a recovery disk:

> If you cannot use the service partition or have had hard drive failure, you will need to obtain a recovery CD or DVD by contacting the Support Center.

So your best bet is probably to try [calling them](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?&LegacyDocID=YAST-3P2QYL).

If it's a case of a lack of optical drive, then you may be instructed to take it to a local Lenovo repair depot to get them to install it, or you may have to purchase yourself an external optical drive.  Just make sure you mention the lack of optical drive to the rep. you speak with, as they probably don't have every model and configuration memorized. ;)